# How to use Youwave in place of Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, youwave-for-android

I've tried for days and failed to run AVD on my PC. So I decided to look for an alternative and found out that Youwave can be used as an emulator. Here is my question: How can I run Android source (apps not finished so they are not .apk) on Youwave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run Android Source which is not finished to become .apk.

The best alternative of emulator is [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com///).

Comment: Thanks. You helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

hopefully it would be useful for others that reach this page through googling,

1. run command prompt in windows by typing "cmd" in the search field of the start menu
2. change the directory to "platform-tools" in your sdk folder. For example, suppose that your sdk is located in "c:\android\source\sdk\" use the command "cd\android\source\sdk\platform-tools" for changing the current directory.
3. Run the following command for connecting YouWave to AndroidStudio:
   "adb connect 127.0.0.1:5558"

Enjoy it!